# how to reduce grid view row and column size in android?

Tags: android

In my application I used  a grid view and in every grid have a image. Now My problem is spacing in between grids are very high. I want to decrease the space in between grids. Please help me.

in xml layout I have used

```
android:verticalSpacing="10dp" 
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
```

now I got a rectangular shape around every image in Xml

my xml for gridview.

```
<GridView 
   android:id="@+id/gridview"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:verticalSpacing="10dp" 
   android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
   android:gravity="center"/>
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
GridView grid;
RelativeLayout r1;
int maxrows, maxcol;
ArrayList<LayoutData> data = new ArrayList<LayoutData>();
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sheetdetails = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();    
@Override   
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    new GetRoute().execute("http://sb2.reloadit.in/TravelServices.asmx/Getlayout");

   }

 private class GetRoute extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
        /*String mJourneyDate;
        public GetData(String pJourneyDate) {
            this.mJourneyDate = pJourneyDate;
        }*/ProgressDialog pd = null;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true);
            }

            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
                String response;

                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                     nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RouteScheduleID","434145405"));

                     nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("JourneyDate","2014-12-18"));


                     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
                    HttpResponse responce = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    HttpEntity httpEntity = responce.getEntity();

                    response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                    Log.d("response is", response);

                    return new JSONObject(response);

                } catch (Exception ex) {

                    ex.printStackTrace();

                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) 
            {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                //Log.v("TAG_RESULTadapter",""+result);

                pd.dismiss();
                if(result != null)
                {
                    try
                    {


                        JSONObject jobj = result.getJSONObject("Response");
                        String message = jobj.getString("Message");
                        String issuceess = jobj.getString("IsSuccess");

                        if(issuceess.equals("true"))
                        {

                            JSONObject layout = result.getJSONObject("Layout");  
                            // Log.v("TAG_routearray",""+layoutarray);
                              maxrows=layout.getInt("MaxRows");

                              maxcol=layout.getInt("MaxColumns");
                              grid.setNumColumns(maxcol);


                                JSONArray routearray = layout.getJSONArray("SeatDetails");
                                for (int i = 0; i < routearray.length(); i++) {

                                 String Row = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Row");
                             // Log.v("TAG_routearray",""+Row);
                                 String Col = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Col");
                                 String Height = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Height");
                              String  Width = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Width");
                                 String SeatNo = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("SeatNo");
                              String Gender = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Gender");

                                     String Deck = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Deck");
                                     String IsAvailable = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("IsAvailable");
                                  String  Fare = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Fare");
                                   LayoutData ld= new LayoutData();
                                    ld.setRow(Row);
                                    ld.setCol(Col);
                                    ld.setHeight(Height);
                                    ld.setWidth(Width);
                                    ld.setSeatno(SeatNo);
                                    ld.setGender(Gender);
                                    ld.setDeck(Deck);
                                    ld.setIsavailable(IsAvailable);
                                    ld.setFare(Fare);
                                    data.add(ld);



                                 Log.v("TAG_Maxfare",""+Fare);
                                 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                 map.put("Row", Row);
                                 map.put("Col", Col);
                                 map.put("Height", Height);
                                 map.put("Width", Width);
                                 map.put("SeatNo", SeatNo);
                                 map.put("Deck", Deck);
                                 map.put("IsAvailable", IsAvailable);
                                 if(SeatNo.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                                     map.put("seat_img", ""+R.drawable.noseat);
                                    }
                                 else{
                                      if(IsAvailable.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
                                          map.put("seat_img", ""+R.drawable.seatgreen);
                                      }
                                     /* if(IsAvailable.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
                                          map.put("seat_img", ""+R.drawable.seatgreen);
                                      }*/else if(IsAvailable.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                                          map.put("seat_img", ""+R.drawable.seat);
                                      }
                                    }
                                 map.put("Fare", Fare);
                                 sheetdetails.add(map);

                                }
                                CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, sheetdetails);
                                grid.setAdapter(adapter);

                        }
                    }


                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
}
```

based on json I added the row and col to grid view

Customgrid:

```
package com.app.redbuslayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
     private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sheetdetails = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
     public CustomGrid(Context c,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sheetdetails) {
         mContext = c;
         this.sheetdetails= sheetdetails;
    }@Override
     public int getCount() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return sheetdetails.size();
     }@Override
     public Object getItem(int position) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return sheetdetails.get(position);
     }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid, null);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

            HashMap<String, String> map = sheetdetails.get(position);
            imageView.setImageResource(Integer.valueOf(map.get("seat_img")));


        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        return grid;
    }
  }
```

rowgrid:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#ffffff" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="15dp"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: put your code here :)

Comment: first try to fix, how many column you want in your GridView, After it use padding in gridview_item.

Comment: columns are based on service. number of columns is dynamic. I get it from service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:numColumns="any_integer"` for definition of the number of items in one row.

For example you have 5 items and you want to decrease horizontal spacing between them. You should put like `android:numColumns="10"`.

Comment: in my application i am dynamically set the number of cols (from service)

Comment: Do you talk about decreasing horizontal spacing or vertical spacing?

Comment: both vertical and horizontal.

Comment: You can take a look at your gridview items' layout's(talking about imageviews). Change widths or heights, play with number of cols, horizontal and vertical spacings. It should not be hard to solve that problem. If you share your codes, we can be more specific about that.

Comment: k i edited my code With xml and activity, I have one adapter  also

Comment: Where is CustomGrid ?

Comment: Finally i want you to post row_grid.xml